# Binutils stat illegal option -c

Tags: macos, gnu, bsd, stat, binutils

I use stat two times in my script once to find the file files permissions and once to find the size of the file.

```
 `stat -c %A "$directory/$file"`
 `stat -c %s "$directory/$file"`
```

I am using OSX 10.7 and directory and file are variable of the current directory I am in and the file.

Comment: Well, type `man stat` and see what options you do have

Comment: btw, it's not a bash question, but a binutils question

Comment: I wonder if ls could be used here to determine permission.

Comment: @ravi ls could determine permission but not size

Comment: can't du be used to determine size?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Darwin `stat` uses an `-f` argument, rather than `-c`, as it is a GNU extension.

You should download the gnu binutils, either from [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), from [macports](https://www.macports.org/) or from [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/), and then use `gstat` instead of `stat`.

If you don't want to install gnu binutils and prefer to stick with the standard BSD tools, then:

```
stat -f%p t.c
```

will return the modes (in octal) and

```
stat -f%z t.c
```

will return the size.

Comment: Or for portability, write a simple Perl script.