# List all folder structure(including subfolders) with last modified time attribute(or all the attributes) in Terminal

Tags: terminal, attributes, timestamp, ls

I'd like to know how to list all folders including the subfolders in, say an external hard drive, with its last modified timestamp(accurate to seconds) in terminal?

I know we can use "ls -lT" to list the timestamp in a certain directory (with files, although I don't need), but I want it to include all the sub-directories as well, with or without the files attributes included.

I also find this command "find . -type d | sed -e "s/[^-][^/]*//  |/g" -e "s/|([^ ])/|-\1/"" could show a directory tree. My wish is to have last modified time stamp besides it.

Thanks guys!
Sincerely,

Comment: `find .` from your parent folder

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But this wouldn't print out the time attributes. It lists out all the directories and files in my hard drive though. :D

Comment: check this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20893429/861487

Comment: Thanks! After installing binutils (as without it it cannot use stat -c argument), I use "find . -type d -exec stat  -c "%n %y" {} \;" to get my work done. This thread does help me! :D

Answer (score 1):

After installing binutils (check https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/), I used

find . -type d -exec stat -c "%n %y" {} \;

to get the work done. Thanks to Abdelouahab and the threads:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20893429/861487

[Binutils stat illegal option -c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666570/binutils-stat-illegal-option-c)